# DataContext change on UserControl not updating child control's property

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I've got this simple control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.ImageToggleButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="480"
             d:DesignWidth="480"
             Loaded="OnLoaded"
             Tap="OnTap"
             Background="{x:Null}">

    <Image x:Name='ButtonImage' />
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class ImageToggleButton
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), OnPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UncheckedImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UncheckedImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), OnPropertyChanged));

        public ImageToggleButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ImageSource CheckedImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)this.GetValue(CheckedImageProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(CheckedImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        public ImageSource UncheckedImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)this.GetValue(UncheckedImageProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(UncheckedImageProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ImageToggleButton)d).UpdateImage();
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateImage();
        }

        private void OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsChecked = !this.IsChecked;
        }

        private void UpdateImage()
        {
            this.ButtonImage.Source = this.IsChecked ? this.CheckedImage : this.UncheckedImage;
        }
    }
```

This control is contained within another `UserControl`, which is used as the `DataTemplate` for a `LongListSelector.ItemTemplate`.

```
(Some xaml snipped for brevity...)
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <controls:ImageToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
                                    CheckedImage="/Assets/icon_checked.png"
                                    UncheckedImage="/Assets/icon_unchecked.png"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Store.IsSelected}"
                                    Height="48" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `DataContext` is a view model with a `Store` member, where `Store` is an object of type:

```
public class Store : NotificationObject
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set { this.Set(() => IsSelected, ref IsSelected, value); }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the `LongListSelector` sets a new `DataContext` for the parent control, the `IsChecked` value doesn't get updated properly on the image.

Comment: Check the debug output when your app is running that particular piece of code. Don't you see any binding errors there? Also, I assume, your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged properly?

Comment: No binding errors, and the VM derives from `NotificationObject` and implements the collection of `Store`s property similarly.

Comment: try using Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the DataContext of your ImageToggleButton.  it looks like your DataContext will be inherited correctly (unless you're setting it explicitly/locally in code we haven't seen here).  can we see the implementation of your this.Set method as called from IsSelected's setter (i don't see that it's a member of NotificationObject, so i assume that you wrote it)?